# Is there an equivalent to .NET's System.Text.Encoding in Java?

Tags: java, encoding

I'm looking for an equivalent to .NET's System.Text.Encoding in Java. For example in C# I can do this:

```
Encoding defaultEncoding = Encoding.Default;
byte[] encoded = defaultEncoding.GetBytes("Text to encode");
```

I would like to be able to do the same in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The java string object has encoding support. getBytes() takes an argument of encoding type. Addendum: Oh and by the way, myStringVar.getBytes() will return platform default encoding of the bytes.

```
String myStringVar = "Text to get bytes for";
byte[] textBytes = myStringVar.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: See also Charset#defaultCharset()